# Apache2 AH00898: Error reading from remote server

Tags: apache, server, apache2, apache2.4

I'm working with node js application to generate excel file with large dataset , and always get error in apache because query to database takes time.

the error seems like this

> [proxy:error] [pid 18903] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /cms/user/printexcel, referer: https://example/cms/user

and here is my apache site config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias example.com
    ServerName example.com 

    RewriteEngine  on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}/     !^(/server-status).*$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$             https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
    <Location "/">
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass "http://localhost:3000/" retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=60000 Keepalive=On
        ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:3000/"
</Location>

    Redirect permanent "/" "https://example.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

please help me if you know how to solve this problem